# Gwent Chain Medic Revives?

Tags: the-witcher-3

In Gwent, is it possible to chain medic revives? For instance, say I have a medic card in my discard pile and a medic card in my hand. If I play the medic in my hand and choose to revive the medic in my discard, do I get to choose another card to revive after that? If so, is it possible to chain this even further?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible to chain medic revives. If you have two medics in your discard and [Yennefer of Vengerberg](http://thewitcher3.wiki.fextralife.com/Yennefer+of+Vengerberg+(Gwent+Card)) in your hand, you can revive one of the medics with Yennefer and then revive the second medic with the first medic.

Comment: Theoretically this can go on for however many times you have medic cards in your discard pile.

Comment: Plus you can use decoys to reuse the same medic card multiple times. That is how I've used one medic card to resurrect multiple cards from my discard pile.